# IHTMLElement -> IAccessible

Tags: winapi, com, accessibility, mshtml

How to get IAccessible from IHTMLElement?

I have receive "Interface is not support" error.

Comment: You could use some better tags if you want others to notice your question.

Comment: That's not what I mean... what is IAccessible? What technology, language, etc are you talking about? Maybe I'm just not so familiar with the tag `com` but based on the number of views I'd say you have to provide some better tags. Language tags are always good.

Comment: @Felix: If you don't know what IAccessible is, chances are you won't be able to answer the question anyway. If you do know what IAccessible is, then you don't need additional tags :)  This is a win32-specific flavor of accessibility, so I've added win32 to indicate that.

Comment: @BrendanMcK: Of course you are right. But the thing is that, I assume, most users here track tags, so it is actually helpful to have some more tags. Anyways, thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all HTML elements are accessible. See [Accessible HTML Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg701963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Accessible_HTML_Elements) (there's also a list of accessible elements [below](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg701963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Accessible_Object_Properties)). You might have hit an element that is not meant to be accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Use IServiceProvider::QueryService - full details at [this article](http://codecentrix.blogspot.com/2007/10/from-iaccessible-to-ihtmlelement-and.html).

Basic idea is that QueryService is like a less strict version of QI: QI requires that all the interfaces are part of the same COM object and uphold certain COM guarantees (shared IUnknown, reflexitivity and transitivity). But QueryService can be used to allow access to related interfaces on separate objects. IE happens to use it a fair bit. To use it, QI the IHTMLElement to IServiceProvider, then use the QueryService method to ask for an IAccessible.